# Android getLatitude() returns geodetic or geocentric latitude?

Tags: android, gps, location, gis, latitude-longitude

Does Android's location.getLatitude() method give a geodetic or geocentric latitude?

If geodetic, is it based on the WGS84 or GR80 ellipsoid?

The API specification is surprising lacking, it only states:

```
public double getLatitude ()

Since: API Level 1
Returns the latitude of this fix.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLatitude()

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: I *think* the devices return a geodetic to the wgs84 model.

Comment: Agree to David, but Still don't have any proof for that As after searching over internet for 2hr I didnt get anything that states it for Android Location services.May be someone from Google dev team can answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geodetic latitudes are used for most common purposes, e.g. maps. It would then be very strange for the API to report anything else. Geocentric latitudes have uses in more specialised and academic fields than mapping.

It's an interesting question (+1) and I'm curious to know if it was geocentric latitudes you were hoping for, and if so what lead to the question.

Your second question: The position is derived ultimately from GPS, whether made from the device itself, A-GPS or not, or trilaterated from the signal strength from the mobile carrier's towers, that in turn have precise GPS positions. And it is the WGS84 ellipsoid that is used with GPS by definition, and not the GRS80 ellipsoid, which differs ever so slightly from WGS84.

I can't prove it, but it's very safe to assume geodetic latitudes based on WGS84.

Comment: I was hoping for the geodetic latitudes based on WGS84, because I'm calculating distances based on the WGS84 ellipsoid, so I'm glad that's what the consensus seems to be.

Comment: I was also looking for this information and another piece of evidence in favour of WGS84, is that most of the functions in the Android Location class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html refer to WGS84.